# EntityFramework - Table per Type (TPT) Inheritance and Mapping Relationships with CodeFirst

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following Entities which I am persisting using EntityFramework CodeFirst:

```
public class User {

     RedGroup RedGroup { get; protected set; }
     virtual ICollection<GreenGroup> GreenGroups { get;  }

     int Id { get; protected set; }
     int? RedGroupId { get; protected set; }
}

public abstract class Group { 

     int Id { get; protected set; }
     virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; protected set; }
}

public class RedGroup : Group {
    // Other properties
}

public class GreenGroup : Group {
    // Other properties
}
```

Essentially, the user can belong to zero or one red groups, and more than one green group.  Each group has a collection of users that belong to it.

I am trying to set up EF using CodeFirst with TPT and am having trouble sorting the mappings.  At the moment, I have the following in `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RedGroupMap());
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GreenGroupMap());
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserMap());
}
```

These are the mapping classes:

```
 public abstract class GroupMap<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T>
     where T : Group {

    public GroupMap() {

        this.ToTable("Groups");

        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnName("Id");

        // Also has other  non-relationship mappings
    }

 }

 public class RedGroupMap() : GroupMap<RedGroup> {

    public RedGroupMap() {

        this.ToTable("RedGroups");

        // Also has other  non-relationship mappings
    }
 }

 public class GreenGroupMap() : GroupMap<GreenGroup> {

    public GreenGroupMap() {

        this.ToTable("GreenGroups");

        this.HasMany(c => c.Users)
            .WithMany(p => p.GreenGroups)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("GreenGroupId");
                m.MapRightKey("UserId");
                m.ToTable("Users_GreenGroups");
            });

       // Also has other non-relationship mappings
    }
}

public class UserMap() : EntityTypeConfiguration<User> {

  this.ToTable("Users");
  this.HasKey(t => t.Id);
  this.Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity).HasColumnName("Id");

  this.HasOptional(t => t.RedGroup)
            .WithMany(t => t.Users)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("RedGroupId"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

I am getting the following runtime error:

`Users: FromRole: NavigationProperty 'Users' is not valid. Type 'RedGroup' of FromRole 'User_RedGroup_Target' in AssociationType 'User_RedGroup' must exactly match with the type 'GreenGroup' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.`

Afraid I'm stumped on how to set up this.

How can I set up the EntityFramework mappings to allow a Table per Type hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a context without your mappings, but with a much simpler configuration and everything appeared to create OK:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().ToTable("Groups");
    modelBuilder.Entity<RedGroup>().ToTable("RedGroups");
    modelBuilder.Entity<GreenGroup>().ToTable("GreenGroups");
}
```

I've noticed that you've defined [User]`.HasOptional(t => t.RedGroup)`, but the RedGroupId field on User is defined as `int` and not `int?` - perhaps this is related?

```
public class User {
     int? RedGroupId { get; protected set; }    // int -> int?
     RedGroup RedGroup { get; protected set; }  // virtual missing, but shouldn't matter

     // Other properties
}
```

If RedGroup is required, try using `.HasRequired` instead.

Comment: From the error message I think the association mappings are what is causing the problem, so if the mappings are missing in your simplified version then I guess the problem wouldn't show up.  

The int? was just a typo.